# PHP mail() not sending an email from contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

When I submit the contact form, it runs the script and redirects back to the header, but no email is ever sent. I think I have some bugs in my code, but can't figure out where.

The HTML code is:

```
<form action="../php/mail.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Email Form" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
                <fieldset>

                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">


                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email">

                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <!--<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Your Password">-->
                    <input id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Your Message">

                    <button type="submit" class="pure-button">Submit</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

The PHP script is:

```
<?php
$from = $_POST["email"]; // sender
$name = $_POST["name"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
mail("myemail@gmail.com","My Contact Form",$message,"From: $from\n");
header( 'Location: http://www.mywebsite.com');
?>
```

Comment: have you got smtp setup correctly? have you posted to the right url?

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed?

Comment: Give more details about the server configuration

Comment: The mail function returns the successful status when the email has been successfully passed on to the mail "agent". It in no way checks whether the mail "agent" actually managed to send it or even if there is one (correctly) installed

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code it will work.

```
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" ;

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
header( 'Location: http://www.mywebsite.com');
```

Comment: can anybody tell me why i got down vote?